# cakephp3でなぜかページの頭に「?」が挿入

Tags: php, cakephp

cakephp3でなぜかページの頭に「?」が挿入されてしまいます。

ページのソース表示をみると確かになぜか、html文書の一番最初（documentタグよりも前）に「?」がついてきます。エラーページも自分で作ったページもすべて同様です。

↓出力されたソース先頭行

```
?<!DOCTYPE html>
```

考えられることについておしえていただけますでしょうか。
BOMが文字化けしているのかなと思い、修正ファイルはすべてBOMなしであることを確認の上バイナリでFTPにアップしてみましたが、それでもだめでした。

環境
さくらインターネット
PHP 5.6 
cakephp3

Comment: マルチポスト　http://www.phppro.jp/qa/4883

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/101509

Comment: ↑こちらのユーザーさんとは全くの無関係なのですが、困っている内容、環境等全く同じ状況でしたのでそのまま文章を流用させていただいて投稿させていただきました。
誤解を招いてしまい申し訳ありますん。
どなたか簡単なヒントだけでもいただければ幸いです。

Comment: PHPコードについてはバイナリではなくアスキーで転送すべきではないでしょうか

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
最初はASCIIで転送していたのですが、試行錯誤のため現在はバイナリで転送してみていまだ改善しないと言った流れです。

Answer (score 3):

同様の質問をされていた方のページの[回答](https://teratail.com/questions/101509)でのやり方で当方も解決しました。

```sh
$ find config -name "*.php" | xargs head -n 1 -q
$ find src -name "*.php" | xargs head -n 1 -q
```

上記コマンドにて探したところ「bootstrap」に?が混ざっており、削除して無事解決することができました。

コメントをくれた皆様ありがとうございました。

Comment: リンクを記載するだけの回答はSOでは好まれません。[良い回答を書くには?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)にもありますが、簡易的でも原因と対策を書いてください。(今回だと例えば「リンク先と同じ原因でbootstrapに？が混ざってました。？を削除することで解決しました。」など）

Comment: 回答方法についてご指摘いただきありがとうございます。
修正いたしました。